# Cloud function: HTTP request name and picture objects undefined

Tags: node.js, http, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

Before a user **first** signed in to the main page of my app, I've done updating user's `displayName` and `photoURL` by calling the following method below.

```
updateUserProfile(name: string, photoURL: string) {
  let data = {
    displayName: name,
    photoURL: photoURL
  };

  this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile(data)
    .then(() => console.log('Updated user profile.'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

However, the problem is when a logged in user makes an HTTP request, the server throws an error.

> Error: Cannot encode type ([object Undefined])

I'm pretty sure this is because `name` and `picture` are **missing!** How can I resolve this problem? Perhaps the token has a problem?

**Note:** *If a user makes HTTP requests after attempting the second login, it works **fine**.*

---

**Client-side code**

```
sendFriendRequest(user: User) {
  this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken().then(idToken => {
    const url = 'https://us-central1-my-db-name.cloudfunctions.net/functionname/api/v1/friend-requests/';
    this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(user), {
      headers: {'Authorization': idToken, 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
    }).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('res', res);
    });
  });
}
```

**Server-side code**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = ({ admin, cors, express, functions }) => {
  const app = express();
  const fireStore = admin.firestore();
  const db = fireStore.collection('friendReqeusts');

  app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log('HEADERS:', req.headers);
    if (!req.headers.authorization) return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Missing Authorization Header' });

    let jwt = req.headers.authorization.trim();

    return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(jwt).then((claims) => {
      req.user = claims; // gives us a user object to use below
      next();
    }).catch((err) => {
      return res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Invalid JWT'
      });
    });
  });

  app.post('/api/v1/friend-requests/', (req, res) => {
    const recipientId = req.body.uid;
    const frRef = db.doc(recipientId).collection('receiveFrom');
    console.log('request body:', req.body);
    console.log('requester:', req.user);
    frRef.add({
      uid: req.user.user_id,
      displayName: req.user.name, // undefined only if a user first signed in
      photoURL: req.user.picture, // undefined only if a user first signed in
      timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      message: "Let's be friends!"
    }).then(() => {
      res.status(200).send({message: 'Friend Requested!'});
    }).catch((error) => console.log("Error writing document: ", error));
  });

  return functions.https.onRequest(app);
};
```

**Expected Behavior**
[image]

**Actual Behavior**
[image]

**SOLVED**

`this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken(true);` Fixed the problem.

bojeil answered my question in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48657191/3252438).