# Firebase: Why am I getting Firebase ID Tokens twice?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

#### Question

From the following situations, I could see two different tokens:

- After completing the sign-up, I get the **first** Firebase ID Token.
- I'm getting a **new** JWT when I come back to my app after completely signing out.

---

#### What I've found

```
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.headers.authorization) 
    return res.status(403).json({ message: 'Missing Authorization Header' });

  const jwt = req.headers.authorization.trim();

  return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(jwt).then((decodedToken) => {
    const uid = decodedToken.uid; // Exists
    const displayName = decodedToken.name; // No displayName, object Undefined
    const photoURL = decodedToken.picture; // No photoURL, object Undefined
    next();
  });
});
```

Even though I've updated the user's default profile by calling the function below, it seems like ID token does not contain user's `displayName` and `photoURL`.

```
initializeUserProfile(name: string, photoURL: string) {
  let data = {
    displayName: name,
    photoURL: photoURL
  };

  this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile(data).then(() => {
    this.getUsersRef(this.currentUserId).update(data); // Save data to firestore
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

**Note:** After the sign-out and successfully logged into the app, the token's length gets much longer than the previous token. Also, it does contain `displayName` and `photoURL` as well.

I've also posted my related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48595793/cloud-function-http-request-name-and-picture-objects-undefined), and it seems like the token causes the problem.

Why am I getting a new token? And how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You don't provide the entire information. It is not clear how you are signing out the user. That piece could shed some light on the issue. Firebase Auth waits for state to be resolved, before signing out the user. This ensures there is no race condition (sign out completes after initial state determined). I speculate that is the reason.

Comment: I presume that you didn't get my question right. After I manually sign out from the app and then when I logged into the app again, the token has changed. Thus, I believe signing out the user isn't the problem.

Comment: I think the state does not get updated even after calling `initializeUserProfile()`.

Comment: Signing in a user will return a new session with a new ID token with full lifetime. Not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: @bojeil How can I get a new session with a new ID token when the user profile gets updated? After calling `initializeUserProfile() ` method. Any ideas?

Comment: This question seems like a moving target. If you want to get a new ID token with the latest claims after you update the profile, you can simply force token refresh `currentUser.getIdToken(true);`.

Comment: @bojeil I've already done that. But it doesn't work during the initial sign in as I expected. If I attempt the second log in after the sign-out, the function works.

Comment: @bojeil It does work! Thank you bojeil. I made a slight mistake in my code. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Cool. To help benefit the community, i will add this as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a new ID token with the latest claims after you update the profile via `updateProfile`, you can simply force token refresh by calling: `currentUser.getIdToken(true)`.

Note, naturally on token refresh when the token is expired, the new token will automatically pick up the latest claims with the profile changes. To get this immediately, you can force refresh.

Comment: I was calling the `getIdToken(true)` in a wrong location. You've pointed out what the actual problem is. Nice catch! and thanks again.